# Drupal flag for node in different block AND styling flag text into buttons

Tags: css, drupal

Two main questions:
I would like to theme the normal Drupal flag text into buttons which remain depressed if the node has been flagged, and visa-versa. Does anyone know how to do this?

Second:
I would like to move the bookmark button into a different location on the site. Can I use blocks to do this, or will I need to build this into the theme?

Thank you so much,

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When you have more than one question, please ask them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Flag Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/node/295346) for help customizing your flag text/buttons.

If by "bookmark" you really mean a flag, read up on [Flag's documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag) to learn how to place flags and more.

Comment: I do mean flags. Are there any established CSS classes for themeing the flags?

Comment: No, the flags have certain id's/classes that are needed for functionality, but there are no predefined classes to use to theme them.  You will need to theme them yourself with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 : which bookmark button you mean....mmm if you mean the Syndicate button then you will find in the blocks the syndicate block which you can control easly

About the first question... please explain more..

thanks